# Arduino project in platform.io

Tags: arduino, interrupt, avr, isr, platformio

I'm building solution based on Arduino framework. Project is compiled in platform.io.

Arduino hardware serial implementation defines `ISR(UART0_UDRE_vect)`.[HW implementation](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial0.cpp)

Is there any possible way to exclude HardwareSerial default implementation or overwrie ISR implementation in custom library ?

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler not to use Arduino framework?

Comment: not in this solution :) code is complicated, and uses most part of arduino i need only disable default hardware serial buffer

Comment: what Arduino model?

Comment: Arduino Pro Mini

Comment: You would need to prevent including HardwareSerial.h. try to add `#define HardwareSerial_h` before `#include "Arduino.h"`

Comment: or better if platform.io has some project settings to add defines for compiler

Comment: @Jurji i tried define HardwareSerial_h before Arduino but linker compiles class from library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183854/discussion-between-juraj-and-kris14an).